# Sync 2 HTML Inputs Range and Number

Tags: javascript, html, input

Hey I'm want to sync 2 inputs so if someone change the slider then should also change the number input and the other way round I know there are other answered Question but the did not work form me because it is important not to change any class names or ids only the number input sync with the slider but not also the other way round my code is:

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="0.25" max="5" value="1" step="0.25" class="slider" id="playbackSpeed">
  <input type="number" value="1" class="number" id="playbackSpeed" placeholder="1,0">
</div>
```

my js is

```
document
  .querySelector(".slider")
  .addEventListener("input", updateValue);
document
  .getElementsByClassName("number")
  .addEventListener("input", updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
  var sibling =
    e.target.previousElementSibling ||
    e.target.nextElementSibling;
  sibling.value = e.target.value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can even shorten the whole thing to:

```js
const inputs=[...document.querySelectorAll("input")];
inputs.forEach((inp,i)=>inp.addEventListener("input",()=>
  inputs[1-i].value=inputs[i].value )
)
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="0.25" max="5" value="1" step="0.25" class="slider" id="playbackSpeed">
  <input type="number" value="1" class="number" id="playbackSpeed" placeholder="1,0">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let range=document.querySelector("input[type=range]");
let number=document.querySelector('input[type=number]')
range.addEventListener("change",(e)=>{
  number.value=e.target.value;
})
number.addEventListener("change",(e)=>{
  range.value=e.target.value;
})
```

For more goto: https://codepen.io/Gangster_sCode/pen/abNKJMm

Comment: Oh thanks a lot it works is there a option to update it instantly not only if you press enter or if you let the mouse button go?

Comment: Use the "input" event instead of "change", see my post ...